# odoo14 auto filled record field in another page when create new record

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I created form view for bank account and i want to make record from bank account automated inserted in bank journal view (journal.account) when its created

```
class BankAccount(models.Model):
_name = 'bank.account'
_description = "Bank Account"

bank_id = fields.Many2one('res.bank', string="Bank")
company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', string="Company", default=lambda self: self.env.user.company_id.id)
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should override `bank.account` `create` method and then create a `journal.account` record.

```
class BankAccount(models.Model):
  _name = 'bank.account'
  
  @api.model
  def create(self, values):
    res = super(BankAccount, self).create(values)
    self.env['journal.account'].create({
     // Journal Account data
    })
    
    return res
```

In case you don't need to create a new journal, but instead update a previously created one:

```
class BankAccount(models.Model):
  _name = 'bank.account'
  
  @api.model
  def create(self, values):
    res = super(BankAccount, self).create(values)
    // Find your journal.account
    journal_account_id = self.env['journal.account'].search([('type','=','bank')], limit=1)

    if journal_account_id:
      journal_account_id.write({
        // Data here
      })

    return res
```

You can also override `write` method if you need to update `journal.account` after updating `bank.account`

Comment: thanks, but how to fill the journal account data when record came from bank.account identified type as bank ?

Comment: @api.model
  def create(self, values):
    res = super(BankAccount, self).create(values)
    journal_account_id = self.env['journal.account'].search([('type','=','bank')], limit=1)
    if journal_account_id:
      journal_account_id.write({
        'acc_number': rec.acc_number,
                'bank_id': rec.bank_id.id,
                'bank_bic': rec.bank_bic,
                'company_id': rec.company_id.id,
                'branch_id': rec.branch_id.id, 
      })

    return res

it shows keyerror when fill the data

Comment: Ensure field names and model names are correct. I assume `journal.account` is a custom model developed by you or integrated by custom modules. If you're referencing to Odoo's Journal, model name is `account.journal`